# Converting xy coordinates in ITRF2000 to long lat WGS84

Tags: convert, coordinates

How can I convert the x y coordinates which are in ITRF2000 coordinate system to long lat WGS84?

Answer (score 1):

[MyGeodata CS2CS online service](https://mygeodata.cloud/cs2cs) can transform XY values pairs from most coordinate systems to any other. Just put your XY coordinates there, choose ITRF2000 as input coordinate system, WGS 84 as output coordinate system and transform.